# When texture painting it uses the cpu to render the effects insted of gpu

Tags: rendering, texture-painting, gpu

The issue is when I'm texture painting when I paint the object blender is using the cpu to show what is happening instead of the gpu. This is becomming an issue as it will take anything froma minute to a few to show the effects.

Comment: mmmmmm  what ?????

Comment: I have a gpu and a cpu when I paint the object as in in texture paint or uv image editor. when I see the results on the 3d view port render through the cpu instead of the gpu.

Comment: You can put a screenshot of your blender settings in the user settings ? and edit your question for what is exactly understood that you just answered

Comment: Screenshots are necessary here. As far as I can tell, GPU is for rendering Cycles for final render as well as render view, but Blender uses CPU for screen rendering and there are ways to make it multithreaded now but still performance depends on how many pixels you are attempting to paint into per face - smaller brushes work better.

Comment: Okay that answered my question.